# Find the indefinite integral:$ \int \sqrt[3]{\frac{x+1}{x-1}} d x $

Tags: integration

$$
\int \sqrt[3]{\frac{x+1}{x-1}} d x
$$
I tried a lot of ways, Wolfram gives me long ugly unswer, and always I came to a lot of partial fractions. I appreciate any help with this example

Comment: It doesn't look that long to me; it just uses a hypergeometric series.

Comment: @J.G. Nice. I just didn't covered those series yet, so I need answer withou them

Comment: I guess you'll have to [rewrite it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If you substitute $$u=\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}$$ the integral becomes $$\int\frac{-6u^3}{(u^3-1)^2}du$$
Then, [Ostrogradsky's integration method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Ostrogradsky#Ostrogradsky%27s_integration_method) will help you.

Comment: Isn't $-6u^3$ in numerator ?